# 'Helvetica Neue' and Helvetica font

Tags: css, fonts

I have seen a few of the the websites using font family:

```
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif
```

I remember reading in some older question here on Stack Overflow that the Helvetica font is not free, and it is available on Mac only, is it so? I'm using Windows XP and I can see that font being rendered is 'Helvetica Neue', and I don't remember installing any font by myself. so all I wanted to ask is if it is safe to use the above font family? (e.g. will most of the Windows computers render those fonts?)

Comment: Arial is very close to Helvetica and comes on Windows.  The Neue variant is typically another matter.

Comment: this Q on topic and answered at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8827/helvetica-neue-equivalent-on-google-fonts/ (also note the linked questions on that page)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Helvetica comes free with Mac but not with Windows. You will have to buy it. But if you have installed Adobe products, it will be installed with many other fonts that come packed with Adobe.

'Helvetica Neue' is the newer version and has slight modification than the older one with correction of few problems that occurred with Helvetica.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use any font in your website you can use this:

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
src: url('Helvetica-Neue-webfont.eot');
src: url('Helvetica-Neue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Helvetica-Neue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Helvetica-Neue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Helvetica-Neue-webfont.svg#Helvetica Neue') format('svg');

  }
```

To use any paid fonts, you should buy the font and put it in your folder. Use this site to create all types of formats: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Answer (score 2):

Helvetica Neue is not free with Windows. However, if you install Adobe software it will install an altered version which can cause problems.

Comment: An example of such issues at  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141362/whats-wrong-with-the-character-encoding-in-the-blog

Answer (score 1):

All windows computers will render that font, if the font is introduced with @font-face in the CSS. With @font-face fonts can be used anywhere on the web page, even if the font isn't installed on the user's computer.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: In the case of Helvetica Neue, which is not a free font, see http://webfonts.fonts.com/ for instructions.

Comment: @different55 FYI I use Helvetica Neue in some of my pages and windows browsers are not rendering it. It may have supported it one time but I don't know that is now.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts The "if" in my sentence carries quite a lot of weight. If you manually upload and include the font, it should work not just on Windows browsers, but on any modern browser.

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica Neue has been blacklisted from @font-face generators like fontsquirrel.

I think the font stack that is quoted in the first post is the best approach.