# Mac System Font @font-face Issue

Tags: css, pdf, fonts, centos, font-face

I'm using Helvetica Neue UltraLight in my `@font-face` (licensing issues are taken care of) and it works just fine via the browser. I'm converting to PDF via WKHTMLTOPDF and I'm having trouble on that side.

If I convert via **Mac** WKHTMLTOPDF 0.10.0 RC2, I get the desired output.

If I convert via **CentOS** WKHTMLTOPDF 0.10.0 RC2, I get the system font.

I set up a bare bones html file to test. In the header, I have a `style` tag with the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'otf';
    src: url(ul.otf) format("opentype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Below it I have similar for eot, ttf, woff, svg, otf base64 encoded, and natively via the font-family (it's also installed on the server).

In the body, I have the following for each:

```
<p style="font-family: 'otf';">OTF: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

The most interesting bit is that I'm also including a Google Font (opentype) that is rendering in the browser, Mac PDF and CentOS pdf (trust me, I've been over the syntax again and again!). Does anyone have a hunch on what's going on here?

[image: CentOS PDF Screenshot]
[image: Mac PDF Screenshot]

Comment: Similar (unresolved) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746240/helvetica-font-not-working-in-wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v0.12.1-dev solves this problem (and introduces new ones that are actively being fixed). Ultimately the bug was in an older version of QT Webkit.