# wkhtmltopdf unable to print unicode character in Ubuntu

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, ubuntu-12.04, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to print PDF from a html which contains Gujarati (Indian Language) characters using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 . O/S is Ubuntu .

**wkhtmltopdf --encoding 'UTF-8'  testutf.html testutf.pdf**

Unfortunately it is printing those characters as small black box as shown below.[image]

I have added the folllowing meta tag in the html .

```
<meta  http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' ></meta>
```

This can be viewed perfectly from browser and also appearing in mail .The html from browser looks as below :

[image]

Can someone please let me know what should be the steps/command to produce proper PDF from this html .

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you find any solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem my be related to not having the correct font available to wkhtmltopdf see [Custom fonts not working in Generated PDF using WKHTMLTOPDF Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295382/custom-fonts-not-working-in-generated-pdf-using-wkhtmltopdf-library?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more information

Comment: The font family was included . But that expected the text to be written using english letters which is typed to produce the font . For example to display નામ I had to put it like <span style="font-family:'varun';font-size:18px;"> GFD </span> . This will be a tedious process . So I am trying to display the text as it is .